# Как подключить онлайн БД к форме через DataGridView в С#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Вот часть кода который я использую.

[image: и скрин созданной формы]

```
using ExampleSQLApp;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class ViewForm : Form
    {
            public ViewForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
            mainform.Show();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            DB db = new DB();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `student or par` (`NameStudent`, `SurNameStudent`, `MiddleNameStudent`, `Pair`, `TimeandData`, `Presence`) VALUES (@name, @surname, @middlename, @pair, @time, @pres);", db.getConnection());

            db.openConnection();
            List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();     
            db.closeConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSuKkF7Ff5g

Comment: Гайд не плохой но мне нужно просто сделать так чтобы он брал данные с MySQL таблицы и вставлял их. Ввод у меня уже осуществлен в другой форме

Comment: есть библиотека, которая работает с MySQL. Её надо подключить к проекту. Затем написать SQL-запрос, потом забрать ответ и разобрать его в грид. Какую именно взять библиотеку, выбор за Вами.

Answer (score 1):

Есть подключение к БД и оно рабочее. Создается команда, которая хранить sql-запрос и сроку подключения.

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

После этого соодаётся "ридер"

```
   SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

потом в цикле читаем данные:

```
   while (reader.Read())
    {
       var NameRegion = reader[0];
       var NameRegions = reader.GetString("Name")
    }
```

А так куда и как выводить - Ваш выбор!

Comment: А можно пожалуйста показать куда это вставлять просто у меня выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @АлександрНеткачёв какую?

Comment: https://af.attachmail.ru/cgi-bin/readmsg?id=16049317681503570551;0;1;5&mode=attachment&email=sasha.netkachev@mail.ru&rid=904547491381917551813852815962896705687 вот такую

Comment: В private void LoadData() и обернуть в try cath. и смотреть где падает.